# Webmasters Tools - What can i do with a exported keywords list?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, keywords

In Google Webmasters Tools you can export the list of keywords. What can you do with this list?

I'm asking this in sense of could something special be done with this comma separated list?
Is there any good software which analyses that?

What do people do with this list?

Comment: Marked Community Wiki per the [Pro Webmasters FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: If marked as community wiki, is this something bad?

Comment: Community Wiki can be used for open-ended questions which do not have a "correct" answer. The [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#WikiPlaceholder-FaqWhatKindOfQuestions) section of the FAQ describes the types of open-ended questions which are considered unproductive and would be closed instead of being left open as Community Wiki questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the keywords shown are any phrase / combination of words your site has appeared somewhere in the results list for, and by somewhere i mean not just the first page.

What this does give you is a good list of phrases you can use in conjunction with your analytics package to start to optimise content on your site around. (if you are using google analytics you may want to take a look at a preview feature which combines the data together: [Pilot Webmaster Tools’ Search Queries data in Google Analytics](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/06/pilot-webmaster-tools-search-queries.html))

You can also collect the data to see how the words change over time, at present you can only see 1 months worth of data so you would need to do this regularly. This would give you seasonal data which would be useful to target marketing.

Right i have just check webmaster tools and the above more relevant to search queries which i find more useful sorry (left in as may well be useful if a little off topic).

With regard to keywords this is a list or groups of words Google has found on your site, i consider it useful for ensuring no spam is being posted the site. Checking you are ranking for the phrases you want to and not something else i.e if it were a recruitment site you would want the phrase job or jobs to be high up on the list. The export also shows the pages Google has found the phrase in which gives you the ability to further optimise those or identify possible areas of duplication. I also keep a list of words i would like to do well for and can therefore use the keywords list to cross reference so as to pick out areas of weakness.